# "Expected Name, found EOF" mutation in Relay

Tags: javascript, eof, graphql, relayjs, graphql-js

Trying to use mutation in Relay, so I create a new "Relay.Mutation" subclass "RemoveMutation" export it and trying to use it in React component. But it always give me this massage:

[image]
``` Uncaught Error: Relay transform error ``Syntax Error RelayMutation (4:14) Expected Name, found EOF ```

I'm using phpstorm and it mark it too:

[image]

Does any one have normal full example how to use Relay mutation? with creating subclass and mutation type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! The problem was in `getFatQuery()` first you have to add `Payload` to your mutation type and next in query you have to use only field you specified in `outputFields`

Comment: Hello @Sarkis, may you please elaborate your answer. I am facing the very same issue.